# Is it possible to set this static private member of a static class with reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a `static class` with `static private readonly` member that's set via the class's `static constructor`.  Below is a simplified example.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    private static readonly string m_myField;

    static MyClass()
    {
        // logic to determine and set m_myField;
    }

    public static string MyField
    {
        get
        {
            // More logic to validate m_myField and then return it.
        }
    }
}
```

Since the above class is a static class, I cannot create an instance of it in order to utilize pass such into a `FieldInfo.GetValue()` call to retrieve and later set the value of `m_myField`.  Is there a way I'm not aware to either get use the FieldInfo class to get and set the value on a static class or is the only option is to refactor the class I've been asked to unit test for?

Comment: Why would you want an instance to get to reflection info? just say `typeof(MyClass)` and off you go into the fun bits of reflection API...

Comment: +1 and would accept the answer if it was such since I completely didn't realize that a Type could be used in Get/SetValue and doesn't have to be an instance of the class itself.  Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is a quick example showing how to do it:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var field = typeof(Foo).GetField("bar", 
                            BindingFlags.Static | 
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Normally the first argument to "SetValue" is the instance
        // of the type but since we are mutating a static field we pass "null"
        field.SetValue(null, "baz");
    }
}

static class Foo
{
    static readonly String bar = "bar";
}
```

Comment: Is this a violation of the "private" access control?

Comment: Generally anytime you use reflection it's a violation of some law :)

Comment: I noticed interesting behaviour. I have `private static readonly` field:
**In .Net Core 3.1** I can set the property with above code.
**In .Net 6** I get an error when I try invoke 
`field.SetValue(null, "baz");`
Exception I've get: `System.FieldAccessException: 'Cannot set initonly static field 'BackgroundCleanerPeriod' after type 'MyClass' is initialized.`

Answer (score 0):

This "null rule" also applies to FieldInfo.GetValue() for a static field, e.g.,

```
Console.Writeline((string)(field.GetValue(null)));
```

Comment: FYI - this should have been a comment to the original answer. This was posted as an answer and does not directly answer the original question which was how to set a value on a static member. This is good info to share, it just should have been as a comment on the answer explaining how to solve to OPs original problem